# Pandas DataFrame: Replacing column values with next column values to avoid duplication

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a Pandas DataFrame with hundreds of rows and 10 columns. Each row represents a unique ID, and each column represents the k nearest neighbor index. That is, the first column would be for the index of the nearest neighbor to the ID, and the second would be the second closest nearest neighbor, etc. down to the 10th closest neighbor.

However, the first column has some duplicates since there are several IDs that share a common nearest neighbor. However, I want to find each ID's nearest neighbor index subject to having no duplication. So for example, if the first two IDs shared the nearest neighbor, then I would want to use the second column for finding the non-duplicated nearest neighbor for the second ID. For example, if my DataFrame looked like this:

```
         NN1        NN2        NN3      ... NN10
1       1           3          8
2       1           5          9
3       1           5          2
4       3           8          1
```

Then the result would be:

```
         NN_no_dup      
1        1
2        5 
3        2
4        3
```

In my example, from what I can tell, there does not appear to be a case where after using a 10th nearest neighbor, that there is still duplicates (and if there are, I can simply increase the number of nearest neighbors I use).

Comment: what happens if let's say the next ID=5, you have the NNs in the order 10,3,11,...  which one you keep, knowing that at row ID=3, in the NN_no_dup you have 10 now while at the origin, 10 was not in the first column NN1

Comment: I would use 11 since that has not been used yet in the NN_no_dup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, although it's surely not the most elegant way:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(....)

used_list = []

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    if np.isin(a.iloc[i,0],used_list):
        take_column = ~np.isin(a.iloc[i], used_list)
        a.iloc[i,0] = a.iloc[i,np.argmax(take_column)]
        
    used_list.append(a.iloc[i,0])
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that there is no particular order of id index, so it's not sufficient to do argmax. I've edited the question to account for this.

Comment: I ended up just doing a for-loop with 10 levels, so the problem is solved since I don't have to run the script again. Still, if anyone has an answer to this problem, it would be interesting to find out how it was solved.

Comment: Why would the order of the index matter? The argmax is there to choose the closest neighbor along a row that did not already appear as a NN1.